# How to play raw data from Apple iPod device using AudioTrack?

Tags: c++, android-2.3-gingerbread, audiotrack

I am on Android Gingerbread writing a middleware application in C++, and I want to play raw PCM samples from the Apple iPhone using AudioTrack.

Is there any test application or tutorial available that I can use for reference?

I have my device node created on */dev/snd/pcmCD3Oc*.